# can we add a Geo replicated brick to the existing glusterfs volume which already has a normal replicated brick

Tags: glusterfs

I have a gluster volume in which presently I have one replicated brick already running.

Now I want to set up a geo-replicated brick, so for this do I need to create a new glusterfs volume and then adding a new brick which will be geo-replicated or I can use the existing glusterfs volume that and add a new brick to it with geo-replication to it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geo-replication works between gluster volumes.

means:

source(master) -> gluster volume

destination(slave) -> gluster volume

volumes contains bricks- but as such you cannot say I want data from only one brick - everything you do is at volume level only.

When you say volume, it means volume already have bricks. (you cannot have volume with zero bricks).

Now, to answer your question:
  - you can create and use a new volume as destination for geo-replication.

Usually, you use clean(empty) volume as your destination(slave) volume.

It is good idea to try out few things locally before actual setup.